# Does it make a difference to add the DEFAULT keyword in CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-database.html) says:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]

ALTER DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

> The database character set and collation are used as default values for table definitions if the table character set and collation are not specified in CREATE TABLE statements.

Someone made a point in the comments, saying:

> It's not at all clear what difference it makes to specify DEFAULT or to omit it. So if you specify DEFAULT then that charset becomes the default for tables for which you don't specify an explicit charset. But what if you omit DEFAULT? Does that prevent tables from using a different charset from the database? This should really be explained above.

Does it make *any* difference if the `DEFAULT` keyword is specified, or are `CHARACTER SET` and `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` just exact synonyms?

Comment: No difference, they are synonyms. `DEFAULT` keyword is optional in that point.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube, do you have any source to back this up? I'd accept that as an answer, by the way ;)